# I am facing this error while submitting the solution on Kaggle Competition-

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

ERROR: Column '' was not expected (Line 1, Column 1)

I have saved the file using below format but issue still exist-

```
submission.to_csv('submission.csv' , index=False)
```

Comment: Not an expert on kaggle, but what does the csv look like?

Comment: Can you post your csv

Comment: I'm voting to close this. No information, no code, no data, possibly incomplete error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the file you created in the program. The file might contains unwanted quotes (",'), which will cause the problem . Please check your file generated before submission function.

Comment: Please be sure that this the exact problem OP is facing before posting an answer. I think this is a guess of yours

Comment: oops. I should ask this and get more clarity of the problem in the comment session only. I recently getting active here .